# Lodash in Angular JS - getting TypeError: Object function lodash(value)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

i've created an application in angular for performing a simple calculator.
The application works fine ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pz5Jc/5/)) but here in the controller within the calculate method i've wrote some arithmetic calculation in javascript. So to make my angular code clean i created another file named common.js where i placed that arithmetic calculations. I'm using lodash.js. but when i tried to call the method `_.calculateResult($scope.firstNumber, $scope.secondNumber, $scope.selectedOperator );` i'm getting the following exception.

```
TypeError: Object function lodash(value) {
      // don't wrap if already wrapped, even if wrapped by a different `lodash` constructor
      return (value && typeof value == 'object' && !isArray(value) && hasOwnProperty.call(value, '__wrapped__'))
       ? ...<omitted>... } has no method 'calculateResult'
    at Object.$scope.calculate (http://localhost:8080/RestSample/app/scripts/controllers.js:18:19)
```

can anyone please tell me some solution for this.

**common.js**

```
(function() {

var calculateResult = function(no1, no2, opp) {
var A = parseInt(no1);
var B = parseInt(no2);
var C = 0;

switch (opp) {
      case '+':
      C = A + B;
      break;
      case '-':
      C = A - B;
      break;
      case '*':
      C = A * B;
      break;
      case '/':
      C = A / B;
      break;                
   }

   return C;
}

})();
```

**controllers.js**

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller("appController", function($scope){
        $scope.operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
        $scope.selectedOperator = $scope.operators[0];

        $scope.calculate = function() {
$scope.result = _.calculateResult($scope.firstNumber, $scope.secondNumber, $scope.selectedOperator );

        };
    });
```

**index.html**

```
    <div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="appController">

     <div class="offset4 span6 well">
     <label>Enter a value :</label>
     <input ng-model="firstNumber" type="text"> <br/><br>


     <label>Another Value:</label>
     <input ng-model="secondNumber" type="text"> <br/><br>

     <label>Operator:</label>
     <select ng-model="selectedOperator" 
     ng-options="operator for operator in operators"></select> 
     <br><br>

     <button ng-click="calculate()">Calculate</button> <br><br>

     Result: {{result}}
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should it work?

When you use lodash, the `_` symbol is usually bound to lodash so you are calling a method on the lodash library with this code:

```
_.calculateResult($scope.firstNumber, $scope.secondNumber, $scope.selectedOperator );
```

And indeed the error message confirms that `_` is lodash.

Moreover, your `common.js` file never exports `calculateResult` to some place accessible to code which is outside your anonymous function. You could export it on `window` if you add this statement at the end of your anonymous function `window.calculateResult = calculateResult` and then you'd call it with:

```
window.calculateResult($scope.firstNumber, $scope.secondNumber, $scope.selectedOperator );
```

This should take care of your immediate problem. (`window` is actually optional in `window.calculateResult(...)` because without it the JavaScript interpreter will still seek `calculateResult` from the global scope but I prefer to make it explicit.)

I would strongly suggest looking into a proper modularization system to avoid polluting the global scope with functions like `calculateResult`.

Comment: but when i called it like `window.calculateResult($scope.firstNumber, $scope.secondNumber, $scope.selectedOperator );` i'm getting `TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'calculateResult'`

Comment: can't we call it like by some other ways `_.calculateResult($scope.firstNumber, $scope.secondNumber, $scope.selectedOperator );`

Comment: Did you add the statement `window.calculateResult = calculateResult` at the end of your anonymous function in `common.js`? If you *did* and you are still getting an error, then the problem could be the order in which your JavaScript is loaded.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd comment, you could probably add a method to lodash named `calculateResult` but my answer to this idea is the same as what I've put at the end of my answer: you should look into a proper modularlization system.

Comment: The code you show in your comment is a bit hard to read but looks correct to me. If you are still getting errors, I suspect the problem is elsewhere (like for instance the order in which your JavaScript gets loaded or executed).

Answer (score 3):

Try ngLodash module, initiate it like you would with any Angular module / plugin. It works complelty without touching window scope and stays with the normal Angular way of loading.

https://github.com/rockabox/ng-lodash

It's on bower also

Bower  install nglodash

Add it into to the html file with a script tag and load it in to the module.